# One PHP Template Page, Call Different Tables with Hyperlinks

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called c33062 that displays data rows in a page. I have twenty other MySQL tables with the same structure and information, just different data. Instead of creating a page for each, I'd like to create hyperlinks for each that then calls that links table information.
My statement is:

```
$query = "SELECT id, year, price_avg_sold, price_sqft, 
          pct_list_sold, adom, sold_nu, sold_chg, 
          year_1, year_2, year_3, year_4, year_5, 
          year_6, year_7, year_8, year_9, year_10 
          FROM c33062";
```

So in essence, I'd like to make hyperlinks for each table, c33063, c33064, c33065 etc that when clicked, would call that particular table's data into the template page.

What would be the correct way to hyperlink the FROM table?

Comment: A `$_REQUEST` would probably be best in this instance. Just ensure the value is treated prior to `sql` use.

Comment: if the structure of the tables are the same, why not have a SINGLE table, and add an extra field to store the "tablename"? `select * from yourtable where table_id='c33062'` is a lot easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Set the table name as variable in each link and get that variable value. 
for example

1. http://www.name.com?tabe=30063 for table 30063
2. http://www.name.com?tabe=30064 for table 30064

and get the table value as **$table =  $_GET['table'];**

then use this variable in query like the code below:
**$query = "SELECT id, year, price_avg_sold, price_sqft, pct_list_sold, adom, sold_nu, sold_chg, year_1, year_2, year_3, year_4, year_5, year_6, year_7, year_8, year_9, year_10 from ".$table;**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to select each table based on a user selection of links:

```
for($i=33062; $i<33081;$i++):
echo '<li><a href="query.php?table=c'.[$i].'"> Link to c'.[$i].'</a></li>';
endfor;
```

in query.php

```
$selected = $_REQUEST['table'];
$query = "SELECT id, year, price_avg_sold, price_sqft, 
          pct_list_sold, adom, sold_nu, sold_chg, 
          year_1, year_2, year_3, year_4, year_5, 
          year_6, year_7, year_8, year_9, year_10 
          FROM $selected";
```

If you want to see the result in the same page:

```
if(isset($_GET['table'])):
   $selected = $_GET['table'];
   $query = "SELECT id, year, price_avg_sold, price_sqft, 
          pct_list_sold, adom, sold_nu, sold_chg, 
          year_1, year_2, year_3, year_4, year_5, 
          year_6, year_7, year_8, year_9, year_10 
          FROM $selected";
   //other codes
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tables have exactly same attributes which you want to retrieve in SELECT statement, you can simply put table names in a query string and retrieve and in your $query, you can get the table name and put it in from condition.

http://example.com?table_name=c33062

http://example.com?table_name=c33062

and in your code,

```
$query = "SELECT <...columns...> FROM ".$_GET['table_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating so many tables (21) with the same schema. It is a bad data stucture.
If all the tables serving same purpose then create only one table and add another column called `entity_name` and pass the value of that field using query string to fetch the row of that entity. To do so:

```
ALTER TABLE c33062 ADD entity_name VARCHAR(64) NULL
```

Then execute the query:

```
$entity_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["entity_name"]);
$query = "SELECT id, year, price_avg_sold, price_sqft, pct_list_sold, adom, sold_nu, sold_chg, year_1, year_2, year_3, year_4, year_5, year_6, year_7, year_8, year_9, year_10 FROM c33062 WHERE entity_name=". $entity_name;
```

And you hyperlink will look like this:

```
<a href="replacewithyourpage.php?entity_name=c33062">c33062</a>
<a href="replacewithyourpage.php?entity_name=c33063">c33063</a>...
```